# How to read class methods attributes in php 8?

Tags: php, attributes, php-8

Lets say I have the following attribute declaration

```
#[Attribute(Attribute::TARGET_METHOD | Attribute::IS_REPEATABLE)]
class Route
{   
    public function __construct(
        public string $path,
        public ?string $method = null,
        public ?string $alias = null
    )
    {}
}
```

and I use it in some controller methods like so:

```
class Controller
{
    #[Route('/index/')]
    #[Route('/home/', alias: 'home')]
    public function index()
    {
        ...
    }
    
    #[Route('/create/', 'POST')]
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

How could I obtain those attribute instances and read it's properties?

Comment: The [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.overview.php) has some example.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson of course. I just made a little research and put together information about usage + reflection reading in a practical way for those people who use to search here in SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by using native php [reflection api](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

First, you will have to retrieve the desired methods reflection.
In the example bellow, I will retrieve all public methods:

```
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass(Controller::class);
$methods = $reflectionClass->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
```

This will return an array containing all public methods reflection.

Then, to read it and retrieve those `Route` instances, simply loop through it and use "newInstance()" attribute reflection method. Like so:

```
foreach ($methods as $method) {     
    $attributes = $method->getAttributes(Route::class);

    echo "reflecting method '", $method->getName(), "'\r\n";
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
       var_dump($attribute->newInstance());
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
reflecting method 'index'
object(Route)#8 (3) {
  ["path"]=>
  string(7) "/index/"
  ["method"]=>
  NULL
  ["alias"]=>
  NULL
}
object(Route)#8 (3) {
  ["path"]=>
  string(6) "/home/"
  ["method"]=>
  NULL
  ["alias"]=>
  string(4) "home"
}

reflecting method 'create'
object(Route)#7 (3) {
  ["path"]=>
  string(8) "/create/"
  ["method"]=>
  string(4) "POST"
  ["alias"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Here is the gist with the full working example:
https://gist.github.com/carloscarucce/fce40cb3299dd69957db001c21422b04